# Displaying an exp bar properly

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have recently started messing around with LWJGL and I was making a little game to test some stuff in. I wanted to try to make an EXP bar and thought that it would be fairly easy. I got almost done with it until I ran into a large issue. That issue is properly displaying the exp bar filling up on the screen.

The game window is 1280 pixels in width and 720 pixels in height. The EXP bar is on the very bottom of the window 10 pixels high and stretches across the entire width of the window. As your level increases, the amount of exp needed to level up also increases. I need some help displaying the amount of exp that you currently have. When you first start you need 100 exp to level up. For example, say I have 50 exp. I need to show the exp bar 50% filled. I am asking for a formula to do this.

I tried looking around the internet for an answer but none of them worked, even though a few seemed like they would work just fine.

Current code to render the filled exp:

```
glColor3f(1f, 0f, 1f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(x, y); // Upper Left
    glVertex2i(x, y); //Upper Right
    glVertex2i(x, y + height); //Bottom Right
    glVertex2i(x, y + height); //Bottom Left
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find what percentage of the experience the player has, and multiply it by the bar's maximum width.

```
int currentXP;
int lastLevelXP;
int nextLevelXP;
int xpBetweenLevels = nextLevelXP - lastLevelXP;
int xpSinceLevelUp = currentXP - lastLevelXP;
float percentageOfXP = xpSinceLevelUp / (float) xpBetweenLevels;
int barWidth = (int) (percentageOfXP * maxWidth); // maxWidth would be the screen's width

// rendering must use 4 unique points
glColor3f(1f, 0f, 1f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glVertex2i(x + (percentageOfXP * maxWidth), y);
    glVertex2i(x + (percentageOfXP * maxWidth), y + height); // where y = 10
    glVertex2i(x, y + height);
glEnd();
```

This way, if the player is at level 2, which starts at 70 XP, has 120 XP, and level 3 starts at 170 XP:

```
currentXP = 120
lastLevelXP = 70
nextLevelXP = 170
xpBetweenLevels = 170 - 70 = 100
xpSinceLevelUp = 120 - 70 = 50
percentageOfXP = 50 / 100 = 0.5

barWidth = 0.5 * 1280 = 640 = half of screen's width
```

Also note that, whereas your code only used 2 different vertices, which would result in a line, mine uses 4 which draws a quad.

**edit**

Since your code resets XP to 0 every level, and simply increases the required amount, the only modification needed is to set `lastLevelXP` to 0 and `nextLevelXP` to the amount of XP needed to level up. Thus, `xpBetweenLevels` becomes `nextLevelXP - 0`, which is the total XP needed to level up; likewise, `xpSinceLevelUp` becomes just `currentXP`. All you need to do is replace the non-rendering code with

```
int currentXP;
int xpNeeded;
float percentageOfXP = currentXP / (float) xpNeeded;
int barWidth = (int) (percentageOfXP * maxWidth);
```

Comment: That code was excluding the my attempt to solve this issue, so the the vertices were the same.

Comment: Also, I think that I messed up in explaining. After you level up, your current exp goes to 0 and the expNeeded goes to a new, higher, number. It does not continue to go up. If it is not too much to ask, could you please change the code to account for this.

Comment: @Kaperly No problem! I've added to my answer.